# Why can I not (re-)install IPv6 on Windows XP Home laptop?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, ipv6

Years ago for some unknown/mistaken reason I uninstalled IPv6 on one of my XP laptops.

I have not been able to reinstall IPv6 - neither via the commandline nor the GUI.

The error message is:

> Could not add the requested component.

The error is:

> A service installation section in this INF is invalid

I have found and read [this](http://windows-xp.itags.org/windows-xp/48931/) and [this](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-21579_102-252569/a-service-installation-section-in-the-inf-is-invalid/) to no avail.

How can I resolve this and reinstall IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

You'll spend the least amount of time on this if you simply format and reinstall. (Hopefully reinstalling something a bit newer than XP while you're at it...)

There are no apparent quick fixes for this issue, and [IPv6 in Windows XP is not particularly suited for actually being used in the real world](https://serverfault.com/a/413398/126632). I'm surprised MS ever released it in the sorry state it's in... oh, wait, no I'm not.